Enable QR scanner in expo development build
I'm switching from ExpoGo to Expo development builds. For some reason, scanning the Metro bundler QR code isn't working if I scan with my camera (android). It opens google search with the app link instead of the development build (which I have installed on my phone).
In ExpoGo, there's a QR scanner you can use to scan expo related QRs, which would get around this issue. However, in development builds, there's no QR code, only a field to manually enter the metro host IP and port.

I can't find any documentation saying why the QR scanner exists in ExpoGo but not Expo dev builds. Is it possible to turn it on?

Scan the qrcode with the built-in camera app.
It should give you an url, and you just have to click on it to open in the development build

This unfortunately doesn't work on google pixels for some reason. I had to download a second QR scanner app to get it to scan properly.

Have you tried to enable the feature in the camera app ?

To clarify, QR codes scan, but they always go to chrome instead of deep linking into the relevant app. It's a known issue on pixels.

Have you tried to login in your CLI with your account and login expo go with the same account ?

Yes, but that's not really relevant here.

No answer for why Expo dev builds don't have QR codes, but I do have an answer for why my phone camera couldn't open the QR code. Turns out google pixels can't scan app links.

google issue tracker
Stack overflow issue 1
Stack overflow issue 2

